# Using T-SQL remove specified words from a string

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to eliminate certain strings from a Description field in a table. To this end I have made this function

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDescriptionClean 
(@strDescription varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

declare @Return varchar(50)
declare @badword varchar(50)

set @badword = 'Front'
set @strDescription = CASE 

--Remove from mid string

WHEN @strDescription LIKE '% ' + @Badword +' %'  THEN REPLACE(@strDescription,' ' +  @Badword + ' ',' ')

--Remove from start of string

WHEN @strDescription LIKE @Badword +' %' THEN RIGHT(@strDescription, (len(@strDescription)-(len(@Badword)+1)))

--Remove from end of string

WHEN @strDescription LIKE '% ' + @Badword THEN LEFT(@strDescription, (len(@strDescription)-(len(@Badword)+1)))
ELSE @strDescription END 

set @badword = 'Right'
set @strDescription = CASE 

WHEN @strDescription LIKE '% ' + @Badword +' %'  THEN REPLACE(@strDescription,' ' +  @Badword + ' ',' ')
WHEN @strDescription LIKE @Badword +' %' THEN RIGHT(@strDescription, (len(@strDescription)-(len(@Badword)+1)))
WHEN @strDescription LIKE '% ' + @Badword THEN LEFT(@strDescription, (len(@strDescription)-(len(@Badword)+1)))
ELSE @strDescription END 

RETURN      @strDescription
end
```

---

I am new to SQL programming and would like to improve on this. Supposing I wanted to have a table which contained a list of 'bad words' that I wanted to be removed from a string and loop through it when cleaning the description.

I should point out that this process needs to be as efficient as possible as I am dealing with 15 millions records.

Comment: SQL server has a 'Replace' function I would suggest using it and replace with ''. Here's a [MSFT link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)  If you're worried about performance you could look into Regular expressions which seem to operate even faster.

Comment: I'm concerned that using the vanilla replace function I will get parts of a word removed leaving me an annoying bit of string. Like if I replace "Run" and it finds "Running" I will be left with "ning". 

I very much want to start using regular expressions but I understand you need to have various priviledges on the database and to have additional software (visual studio?) installed on the computer - so at the moment this isn't an option.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the concern.  However it's a problem you can't avoid in full.  the only way to truely mitigate this issue is visual inspection of every entry; with an approval process.  even with your technique you'd run into problems with it at the end of a sentence.  BADWORD.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Why don't you just use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)?

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName,'specific word','');
```

Comment: You can also pad this with leading and trailing spaces, if you want to check for partial words.

Comment: What if your 'specific word' is something like, say, 'key' or 'ore', which can easily occur in other words (such as 'monkey' or 'bore',for example).  Won't you be left with partial works (in my example, "mon", or 'b').